# How to remove these water droplets between two layered glass window?

Tags: cleaning, home, glass

It's winter season and there are water droplets on window glass. So this window is above air conditioner and if we want to clean up, we have to unscrew screws and open it.

I want to clean up these water droplets to have a clear view from window. This is a two glass window and droplets are formed in between two glass.

Is there any way to clean these water bubbles without opening the screws ?[image]

Comment: Impossible to tell from the picture or description... is this double-glazing that has leaked out the inert gas, DIY double-panes with no atmospheric control at all, or just single-glazing??

Comment: I'm not sure. It's a two layer window.

Comment: You have to know - the answer depends on it.

Comment: There is no gaseous stuff between two layers of this sliding window.

Comment: @GC 13: Posting a good picture of the frame would help.

Comment: From the description it's a DIY double pane (hence the nails/screw that attach the second pane to the frame).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a single-glazed window, use a hair-dryer or other *gentle* heat source, kept moving over the glass, to evaporate the water condensation. Afterwards, place a baffle of some sort, e.g. sheet plastic, to direct cold air away from window and/or add additional insulation, to help prevent condensation again.

Comment: Worked perfectly

Answer (score -2):

If I were you I would  open tiny mini hole at the bottom of inner glass you mentioned as like as windows at airplanes.

Comment: without knowing what the glazing type is, this is not vaguely an encompassing answer. If it's a sealed-unit then you are recommending actually drilling the glass itself??

Comment: From the pic i can easly say that there is no gas or left  any in middle  . Yes of course you can not  use drill to do  that  but if you let your inner section breath somehow (very small hole on glass )  there will never be water drops.

Comment: won't it then lose much of insulative capacity ?